# Jumping diagonally with key listener

Tags: java, animation, sprite, keylistener

I have the character being able to move side to side very well. I have tried jumping and I can't seem to figure it out. Also, I am having trouble getting the character to jump diagonally and have it look kind of decent. Any help would be greatly appreciatedI was also thinking about having a timer running that only allows the user to jump every 5 seconds.

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
repaint();
x+=velX;
height += velY;
if (height >= totalHeight){//total hieght is the max height the character can travel however
//If the user spams the W key the character will just keep going
  y+=velY;
}else{
  y+=gravity;
}
firex += velF;
if (y < 2){
  y = 3;
}
if (y >530){
  y = 531;
}   
}
public void right(){
velX = 20;
}
 public void left(){
 velX = -20; 
 }
 public void fire(){
 velF = 15;//This is a projectile//THis also should be on a timer, for every 10 seconds it can shoot once
 }
 public void jump(){
  velY = -30;
  }


public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
int code = e.getKeyCode();
//NEED HELP WITH JUMP LEFT AND JUMP RIGHT//
//I WANT TO MAKE IT SO THAT HE DOESNT LOOK WIERD?GLITCHY//
//FIND OUT ABOUT COUNTER FOR ENEMIES NEARBY,LIKE IF AN ENEMY IS NEAR YOU FOR 2 SEC YOU LOSE HEALTH
if(code == KeyEvent.VK_Z){
  firex = x;
  firey = y;
  fire();
  fireIs = true;
  isMovingRight = false;
  isNotMoving = false;
  isPunch = false;
  isMovingLeft = false;
  isKick  = false;
  isJump = false;
   isSlam = false;
}
if (code == KeyEvent.VK_P){
  System.out.println("Paused");
  stopAnimation();
}
if (code == KeyEvent.VK_A){
  left();
  isMovingRight = false;
  isNotMoving = false;
  isPunch = false;
  isMovingLeft = true;
  isKick  = false;
  isJump = false;
   isSlam = false;
}

if (code == KeyEvent.VK_F){
  isPunch = true;
  isNotMoving = false;
  isMovingRight = false;
  isMovingLeft = false;
  isKick  = false;
  isJump = false;
   isSlam = false;
}

if(code == KeyEvent.VK_D){
  right();
  isMovingRight = true;
  isNotMoving = false;
  isPunch = false;
  isMovingLeft = false;
  isKick  = false;
  isJump = false;
   isSlam = false;
}
if(code == KeyEvent.VK_Q){
  isMovingRight = false;
  isNotMoving = false;
  isPunch = false;
  isMovingLeft = false;
  isKick  = true;
  isJump = false;
   isSlam = false;
}
if(code == KeyEvent.VK_W){
  jump();
  isMovingRight = false;
  isNotMoving = false;
  isPunch = false;
  isMovingLeft = false;
  isKick  = false;
  isJump = true;
   isSlam = false;
}
            if (code == KeyEvent.VK_E){
  isPunch = false;
  isNotMoving = false;
  isMovingLeft = false;
  isMovingRight = false;
  isKick  = false;
  isJump = false;
  isSlam = true;
  }
  }
  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}
  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
  int code = e.getKeyCode();

  if(code == KeyEvent.VK_D){
  isMovingRight = false;
  isNotMoving = true;
  isPunch = false;
  isMovingLeft = false;
  isKick  = false;
  isJump = false;
   isSlam = false;
 // System.out.println(getX());
}
if (code == KeyEvent.VK_P){
  startAnimation();
}
if (code == KeyEvent.VK_A){
  isMovingRight = false;
  isNotMoving = true;
  isPunch = false;
  isMovingLeft = false;
  isKick  = false;
  isJump = false;
   isSlam = false;
}
if(code == KeyEvent.VK_Q){
  isMovingRight = false;
  isNotMoving = true;
  isPunch = false;
  isMovingLeft = false;
  isKick  = false;
  isJump = false;
   isSlam = false;
}
if (code == KeyEvent.VK_F){
  isPunch = false;
  isNotMoving = true;
  isMovingLeft = false;
  isMovingRight = false;
  isKick  = false;
  isJump = false;
   isSlam = false;
}
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_E){
  isPunch = false;
  isNotMoving = true;
  isMovingLeft = false;
  isMovingRight = false;
  isKick  = false;
  isJump = false;
  isSlam = false;
}
if(code == KeyEvent.VK_Z){
  isMovingRight = false;
  isNotMoving = true;
  isPunch = false;
  isKick  = false;
  isJump = false;
   isSlam = false;
}
if(code == KeyEvent.VK_W){
  if (y > 100){
    isMovingRight = false;
    isNotMoving = true;
    isPunch = false;
    isMovingLeft = false;
    isKick  = false;
    isJump = false;
     isSlam = false;
    height = 0;
  }else if (y < 540){
    isMovingRight = false;
    isNotMoving = false;
    isPunch = false;
    isMovingLeft = false;
    isKick  = false;
    isJump = true;
     isSlam = false;
    height = 0;
  }
}
velX = 0;
```

}

Comment: A little more detail as to what is going wrong would help. When you jump, does the player just fly up forever? That would be my guess since I see nowhere in the code for velY to get set back to zero when the player is done jumping.

Still, I'm not exactly sure what I should be looking for since I don't know why you're not happy with the jump.

Comment: When you press once it works fine. The player only jumps for 150 pixels. However, when the user spams the W key the character bypasses the height set and keeps going above 150 pixels. That is what I am unhappy with. I was thinking of only allowing the user to press the W key every few seconds but I can't seem to figure how to do that.

Comment: @JozefBrudnicki Only allow them to jump when they're touching the ground.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I thought about that but then i realized i need the user to be able to jump onto platforms in the air(kind of like super mario with the bricks is the air. The simplest solution i came up with would be having a timer, which i dont know how to do and i can't seem to find any clear explanations/examples.

Comment: @JozefBrudnicki Then only allow the player to jump when they're feet (or just the bottom of them) is touching something

Comment: @Carcigenicate How would I go about coding that?

Comment: @JozefBrudnicki Through some form of collision detection. If you do just want to use a timer, whenever the player jumps, save the current time in milliseconds, then don't let them jump again until `currentTime >= lastJumptime + 5000`, where 5000 is the number of ms between jumps.